# Apply CSS outside the selector

Tags: css

I want to make the border of my error select box outside div.wwctrl color red. The problem is it doesn't changed it color using advance css selector. I want to use css and not javascript to implement this. Is this possible? Thank you.

```
<div class="wwctrl">
    <select id="error" name="summaryData.type"></select>
</div>

.wwctrl {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid pink;
}

select#error + div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
​
```

[SAMPE CODE - JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s6LbB/1/)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: What is an advanced CSS selector?

Comment: @Max how is that related to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do so with CSS.

Most important:  IDs (`#`) are only allowed to be used on one element in the whole document, so if you want to apply an identifier to several elements, you have to use a class (`.`)!

You just declare the border for the selectbox outside `wwctrl`.

```
select.error{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Now you override this selector with a more specific selector for the error boxes inside `wwctrl`:

```
.wwctrl select.error{
   border-color:pink;
}
```

Because the rule is more specific, it overrides the previous rule.

```
<div class="wwctrl">
  <!-- has a pink border -->
  <select class="error" disabled="disabled"><!--...options...--></select>
  <select><!--...options...--></select>
</div>
<!-- outside wwctrl - has a red border -->
<select class="error" disabled="disabled"><!--...options...--></select>
```

**[Your modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/s6LbB/3/)**

Comment: i want the border to be in the div.wwctrl not in the select box itself

Comment: doesn't matter, it's the same procedure. Just add an extra `+div` to my selectors.

Comment: Sure it is: http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/s6LbB/4/ Or did i misunderstand your question? What exactly do you want?